# Can't restore mysqldump --all-databases in CLI mode with error 3723 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line-interface

I have created a mysql backup utilizing `mysqldump --all-databases` as recommended by the documentation, however when I am trying to restore it on a new system with freshly installed MySQL 8 I get the following error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -e "source /root/Backups/dbs-backup-2022-02-08.sql"
ERROR 3723 (HY000) at line 481 in file: '/root/Backups/dbs-backup-2022-02-08.sql': The table 'replication_asynchronous_connection_failover' may not be created in the reserved tablespace 'mysql'.
```

Credentials to the root user are passed with .my.cnf

In interactive mode the backup is restored however the output is so big that I can't figure out whether the error was encountered or not.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql
mysql> source /root/Backups/dbs-backup-2022-02-08.sql
[...]
mysql>
```

How do I find out if the error was encountered during the restore process?

Why can't I restore the backup in CLI mode?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what -e does, even from the mysql help, but try this
mysql < /root/Backups/dbs-backup-2022-02-08.sql
Its how i do a restore and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
mysql -uroot -p 
source dump.sql
```

Comment: This is not the same situation. @CasualRascal has a full backup. The backup includes tables of 'mysql' schema.